unexpected character was encountered:
I am using Power Automate tools to send cards in MS teams.
This is my payload to send message in channel.
{
   "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
   "type":"AdaptiveCard",
   "version":"1.5",
   "body":[
      {
         "type":"TextBlock",
         "text":"@{body('Parse_JSON')?['title']}",
         "size":"Large",
         "weight":"Bolder",
         "wrap":true
      },
      {
         "type":"TextBlock",
         "text":"@{body('Parse_JSON')?['text']}",
         "isSubtle":"true",
          "wrap":true
      }
   ]
}

However, I get Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: r. Path ‘body[1].text’, line 15, position 26., this is because my data contains escaped double quotes (example below)
{
  "title": "Testing Please Ignore ",
  "text": "\"reason\":\""
}

If i put clean text , request goes through and I can successfully post a message in a channel

cannot really see the issue here as you have already placed escape characters.
I reproduced the same thing and it works. Please tally with this flow if you're doing something odd?



I do exactly like you, however error arises in "send a card in teams" step which is missing in your flow
